# How to exclude bash input arguments in "$*"

Tags: bash, variables, arguments

Basically, I want to be able to call $* in a bash script, to represent all arguments after the script is called, but I want it to ignore the first two. ($1 and $2)

So for simplicity's sake, if all the script did was just echo back the arguments, it should behave as such:

```
$ myscript.sh first_argument second_argument foo bar baz blah blah etc
foo bar baz blah blah etc
```

Is there an easy way to do this?  By the way, there should be no limit to the amount of text after the first and second argument, if that amount were known, I could easily call them individually, like $3 $4 $5 $6 ...

I hope that was clear.

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably [shift](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html) will help you.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a variant of array slicing to pick out a range of arguments.  To print the arguments from 3 on, use this:

```
echo "${@:3}"
```

Unlike the `shift`-based option, this doesn't mess up the argument list for other purposes.

Answer (score 5):

Use `shift`:

```
#!/bin/sh

shift 2

echo $@
```

`./myscript A B C D` outputs `C D`.

This will fail if there are fewer than 2 arguments, use `$#` to check.

Here is a fairly comprehensive [documentation of shift](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html).

Comment: Add a link to some docs to your answer and I will remove my answer as yours is more complete :)

Comment: You cannot delete an accepted answer... Hey, OP, his answer is really better! Select it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this puts all the args except the first two in an array, which you can then loop over or whatever.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a args

count=1
index=1
for arg in "$@"
do
    if [ $count -gt 2 ]
    then
        args[$index]=$arg
        let index=index+1
    fi
    let count=count+1
done

for arg in "${args[@]}"
do
    echo $arg
done
```

Comment: Although the shift option seems more concise. :)